# Terraform resource isn't reading updated value of another resource correctly

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I don't know if this is a Terraform issue or the provider has a bug.

I'm using kubernetes_deployment and kubernetes_config_map.

In kubernetes_deployment I have this:

```
template {
  metadata {
    labels = {
      config_version = kubernetes_config_map.myconfig.metadata[0].resource_version
```

This is what happens:

1. I modify the config file the kubernetes_config_map resource is using
   and run apply
2. Terraform sees the config map resource change but the
   kubernetes_deployment resource doesn't show any changes
3. After I apply I run apply a second time
4. Now kubernetes_deployment sees the changed value and registers it as a change

This happens with or without an explicit depends_on.

Why is this happening? kubernetes_deployment should be seeing the value has changed and register that as a change too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't paying attention to what was happening.

I *think* this is a bug in the kubernetes_config_map resource.

When the config map data is modified the kubernetes_config_map resource only surfaces a change in the "data" attribute and this is the wrong behavior causing my issue.

If data is modified then the resource_version MUST and will always change, but the resource doesn't register this change. Because of this dependant resources looking at that attribute don't see any changes.

Too bad because that would be a really clear way to to this.

Fortunately until that bug is fixed I can use a hash of the data attribute:

```
template {
  metadata {
    labels = {
      config_hash = md5(kubernetes_config_map.myconfig.data)
```

Comment: That does indeed seem like a missing behavior in the provider. If, as you say, a change to the data would cause `resource_version` to change then in principle a provider can mark that `resource_version` argument as "known after apply" during the plan phase in that case, which should then get the behavior you were expecting. Perhaps you could report that in the provider's repository to see if it's possible to implement that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This was actually an intentional [design decision](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/737#issuecomment-650810892) in the provider, since Deployments in Kubernetes do not [currently](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22368) restart when a ConfigMap or Secret are modified. There are a few ways to get the desired behavior, both in Terraform and Kubernetes:

1. Mount the Secret or ConfigMap as a volume and use a hot-reloading mechanism in the application code (e.g [viper](https://medium.com/@xcoulon/kubernetes-configmap-hot-reload-in-action-with-viper-d413128a1c9a)) or a sidecar container like [weaveworks/watch](https://github.com/weaveworks/Watch).
2. Run a controller that ensures deployments are using the latest configuration, such as [stakater/reloader](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader) or [pusher/wave](https://github.com/pusher/wave).
3. Add an annotation to the Deployment or Daemonset that is a hash of the data in your config_map and secret. Here is an example:

```
    annotations = {
        config_change = sha1(jsonencode(merge(
            kubernetes_config_map.test_config.data,
            kubernetes_secret.test_secret.data
        )))
    }
```

The downside of #3 is that you will have to duplicate this code for every deployment that uses a particular configmap/secret. It also creates some noise in the diff that may not be immediately intuitive to someone making a config change who didn't set this up.